# Splitting file based on data comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been recently using a Garmin GPS path tracker which produces files like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="GPS Track Editor" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gte="http://www.gpstrackeditor.com/xmlschemas/General/1" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" targetNamespace="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" elementFormDefault="qualified" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<metadata>
    <name>Ślad_16-SIE-15 190121.gpx</name>
    <link href="http://www.garmin.com">
        <text>Garmin International</text>
    </link>
</metadata>
<trk>
    <name>16-SIE-15 19:01:21</name>
    <trkseg>
        <trkpt lat="55.856890" lon="-4.250866">
            <ele>9.27</ele>
            <time>2015-08-16T08:32:13Z</time>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="55.856904" lon="-4.250904">
            <ele>6.39</ele>
            <time>2015-08-16T08:32:15Z</time>
        </trkpt>

...

        <trkpt lat="55.876979" lon="-4.286995">
            <ele>46.28</ele>
            <time>2015-08-16T17:22:14Z</time>
        </trkpt>
    <extensions>
        <gte:name>#1</gte:name>
        <gte:color>#fbaf00</gte:color>
    </extensions>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

The thing is that sometimes the device is losing signal (when in an inner city for example), which causes a footpath to be interpolated in an unpleasent manner:

[footpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk2Dw.jpg)

I would like to split the footpath file into three separate files (to avoid these long arrows - see picture).
I ended up with following decomposition of a problem:

1. Read the original file latitude (lat) and longitude (lon) values
2. Compare 2 consecutive lat and lon values until assumed difference is
   met while saving them to file one.
3. Add ending to file one, add predata tags to file two, continue with
   comparing

Since I'm trying to learn Python 2.X, I'm stuck with this:

```
gpxFile = open('track.gpx', 'r')
with open("track.gpx", "r") as gpxFile:
    data = gpxFile.read()
    print data
    for subString in data:
        subString = data[data.find("<trkpt")+12:data.find("lon")-2] + " " + data[data.find("lon")+5:data.find(
            "<ele>")-6]
```

Can anybody help me with that or at least give me a heads up of what to look for in a documentation or tutorials?

Thanks.
Cheers!

Comment: You could look for a module to read xml, for example https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't perfect, but it should do what you want. If not, it should serve as a good starting point. It works by reading in the XML file, extracting all of the track points, and then finding the gaps based on the timestamps. For each group of points, it outputs a new file named original_N.gpx (N = 0,1,2,...) where the input file is original.gpx. It could be modified to use distance between points, but time seemed a little easier. Look at `delta_too_large(pt1, pt2)` to change the gap detection, currently two seconds.

[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/sr105/e7d651e9c96a67d80e41) (Public Domain)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (C) 2015 Harvey Chapman <hchapman@3gfp.com>
# Public Domain
# Use at your own risk.

"""
Splits a gpx file with breaks in the track into separate files.

Based on: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33803614/47078
"""

import sys
import re
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import izip
from xml.etree import ElementTree

ns = { 'gpx': 'http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1' }

def iso8601_to_datetime(datestring):
    d = datetime(*map(int, re.split('\D', datestring)[:-1]))
    # intentionally ignoring timezone info (for now)
    # d = d.replace(tzinfo=UTC)
    return d

def datetime_from_trkpt(trkpt):
    datestring = trkpt.find('gpx:time', ns).text
    return iso8601_to_datetime(datestring)

def delta_too_large(trkpt1, trkpt2):
    delta = datetime_from_trkpt(trkpt2) - datetime_from_trkpt(trkpt1)
    return delta > timedelta(seconds=2)

def trkpt_groups(trkpts):
    last_index = 0
    for n, (a,b) in enumerate(izip(trkpts[:-1], trkpts[1:]), start=1):
        if delta_too_large(a,b):
            yield last_index, n
            last_index = n
    yield last_index, len(trkpts)

def remove_all_trkpts_from_trkseg(trkseg):
    trkpts = trkseg.findall('gpx:trkpt', ns)
    for trkpt in trkpts:
        trkseg.remove(trkpt)
    return trkpts

def add_trkpts_to_trkseg(trkseg, trkpts):
    # not sure if this will be slow or not...
    for trkpt in reversed(trkpts):
        trkseg.insert(0, trkpt)

def save_xml(filename, index, tree):
    filename_parts = os.path.splitext(filename)
    new_filename = '{1}_{0}{2}'.format(index, *filename_parts)
    with open(new_filename, 'wb') as f:
        tree.write(f,
                   xml_declaration=True,
                   encoding='utf-8',
                   method='xml')

def get_trkseg(tree):
    trk = tree.getroot().findall('gpx:trk', ns)
    if len(trk) > 1:
        raise Exception("Don't know how to parse multiple tracks!")
    trkseg = trk[0].findall('gpx:trkseg', ns)
    if len(trkseg) > 1:
        raise Exception("Don't know how to parse multiple track segment lists!")
    return trkseg[0]

def split_gpx_file(filename):
    ElementTree.register_namespace('', ns['gpx'])
    tree = ElementTree.parse(filename)
    trkseg = get_trkseg(tree)
    trkpts = remove_all_trkpts_from_trkseg(trkseg)
    for n, (start,end) in enumerate(trkpt_groups(trkpts)):
        # Remove all points and insert only the ones for this group
        remove_all_trkpts_from_trkseg(trkseg)
        add_trkpts_to_trkseg(trkseg, trkpts[start:end])
        save_xml(filename, n, tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: {} file.gpx".format(sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(-1)
    split_gpx_file(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Works like a charm after adjusting timedelta to 1200 seconds. Thank you! A piece to learn from.